# Load Listview about million items

Tags: android

Now,I must do work as title.
Each item in listview is rather complicate,it contains 5 image loaded from Internet.
I think use lazy load but data load from Internet very large(million items),so this ways not reasonable..
I also think other ways.Before scroll listview,I will load item belowThat is my thoughts.but I don't progress it by code.

Do you have done this.Help me.!

Answer (score 0):

If i am thinking correct then you want to delete row from listview. But after that you need to download your data again from internet. I dont think its a good idea. And I also dont think that it will effect to listview. every time when you scroll your listview it just reinflate your views of your row and set data on it. So if you will delete data from your arraylist or array it will remove that row.

```
public my_custom_adapter(Context context, int type, String[]  elements)
{
    super(context, type, elements);
    this.elements =  elements;
    this.context = context;
}
```

in above example my_custom_adapter is the adapter which is extending arrayadapter. If you look in super constructor then i am passing elements as a String Array. To delete a row from your listview what you can do is you can delete element from "elements" and then call

notifyDataSetChanged();

this will reduce a row from your listview.

Hope it will help you..

Comment: Is is working you have tested... Welcome so I am correct.. if it is help full then mark it as answers so that other should not waste time on it and it will increase my points too.. :)

Comment: Here I want to load item below current item that is displaying..when i scroll listiview,below items are loaded and display .When listview will not lag.I don't delete above item.That is my thoughts.I can write not clear:)

Comment: not able to understand what you are saying... What i have understand is you have millions of items to download and millions of rows also. So problem will be that it will take alot of time to display listview. So what you want to do is that when it load one item then add it in listview... am i write..